# Stack Exchange One-Click Reviews

Tags: script, review

### About

The new UI for reviews introduced in early 2021 requires two clicks to submit reviews for an item: once to select the action, and a second time to submit the review. By contrast, the previous UI simply required a single click on an action button to submit a review.

Some users prefer the old behavior of simply having one click to submit a review. This script removes the requirement for a second click on the Submit button, and makes it so that clicking on a review action will immediately submit the review, restoring the former behavior of the old queue layout.

#### Notes

- To discourage robo-reviewing, there is a slight delay baked into the script: if you click on a review action too early, it will simply select the button without submitting the review.

#### Download

[Link to install the user script](https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/gparyani/2bcc29740ab0da5fe38eff84e2a45efd/raw/d548b0b9a7a9480471d7888fa1ce64ea9462be14/oneclickreview.user.js). You will need to have a user script manager extension installed in your browser, such as Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey.

#### Platform

Tested with Tampermonkey on Microsoft Edge (new Chromium-based version) on Windows. Haven't tested with other browsers or user script managers, but should work with other platforms too.

### Code

[Source code](https://gist.github.com/gparyani/2bcc29740ab0da5fe38eff84e2a45efd)

Answer (score 0):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

> To discourage robo-reviewing, there is a slight delay baked into the script: if you click on a review action too early, it will simply select the button without submitting the review.

That's an excellent feature, but can it be disabled for the 'Edit' option? That option requires the user to do something meaningful in the post editor before actually submitting the review. I can't see any problem in activating the editor immediately after clicking that option.

Comment: It's actually a by-product of using a JS `setInterval` to repeatedly apply the event handler to each button, as the page doesn't fully reload for each review. To implement this would require me to add in a new routine to add the event handlers immediately upon each load, and to only add it on certain review buttons. As the delay is *extremely* slight, quite shorter than the time a reasonable reviewer would take for any action including ones that require further input, I decided it wasn't worth it.

Comment: Yes, after submitting an edit the review is completed and I sometimes need to go back to do some voting, that's right. Maybe I should adjust my workflow then :)